# Remove Different Phrases

Tags: vba, ms-word

I tried to replace the following phrases (goes further to 150 each) with the empty string "":

```
[1]
[2]
...
[150]

<1>
<2>
...
<150>

<1/>
<2/>
...
<150/>
```

The following Solution would work, if it would not be to much code. How can in simplify this tho replace every single mentioned phrase with the value null ""?

```
 Sub Encoder()
'
' Encoder Makro
'
'
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "[1]"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        With Selection.Find
        .Text = "[2]"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
...... >>>> and so on with all the other phrases
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a for loop to loop over all integers you want to change.
In the snippet below 'i' is the starting number higherEnd after the loop exists.
You can see the concatenated string if you remove the "'" from the Debug line.

```
Sub renameYourNumbers(higherEnd As Integer)

        Dim i As Integer

        i = 1
        For i = 1 To higherEnd

            Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            With Selection.Find
            .Text = "[" & CStr(i) & "]"
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindAsk
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            End With

            'Debug.Print ("[" & CStr(i) & "]")
        Next

End Sub
```

You can call this function by

```
Call renameYourNumbers(150)
```

Comment: Good. You can improve this by using wild card to handle every braces. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For your need best is to use wild card to handle your pattern.
Try this

```
Sub Demo()
    With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
        .Text = "[\<\(\{\[\\\/]{1,2}[0-9]{1,5}[\>\}\]\)\\\/]{1,}"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

for 1-150, try this

```
Sub renameYourNumbers()

        Dim i As Integer

        i = 1
        For i = 1 To 150

            Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            With Selection.Find
            .Text = "[\<\(\{\[\\\/]{1,2}" & CStr(i) & "[\>\}\]\)\\\/]{1,2}"
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

            End With

            'Debug.Print ("[" & CStr(i) & "]")
        Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You can also combine this answer with Pydan's answer.

Comment: Does this Code replace all the variations of brackets from 1-150? 
Where does it say to go up to 150? Thank you very much.

Comment: no it goes from 0-99999. in the middle there is [0-9]{1,5} where the {1,5} says number of occurrence. {1,3} will give you 0-999. If you specifically want the answer for 1-150 you should combine the answers of mine with pydan's